# Laravel Illegal offset type on many to many with extra column

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

in Database i have a table of product and components
and i have a table for many to many relation which is component_product
it have an attributes of (product_id,component_id,quantity)

in model product

```
class Product extends Model
{
      protected $fillable = [
         'name','price','user_id','is_avilable','description'
     ];

     public function components()
     {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Component')
            ->withPivot('quantity');
     }
}
```

in view

```
{!! Form::select('component_id[]',$components,null !!}
{!! Form::select('component_id[]',$components,null !!}
{!! Form::number('quantity[]',null ]) !!}
{!! Form::number('quantity[]',null ]) !!}
```

in controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
         $product= Product::create( $request->all() );
         $product->components()->sync($request->component_id => ['quantity'=> $request->quantity ] );

}
```

It gives me an error of Illegal offset type

> notice : if die dump $request->quantity or $request->component_id it will get the array correctly

Comment: FWIW, I had the same issue where I had a collection of `User` instances. I was scratching my head wondering what was wrong. _Then I read the documentation._ It needed to be a **collection of IDs**. The moral of the story: _always read the docs_.

Answer (score 0):

Sync example in laravel docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)

```
$user->roles()->sync([1 => ['expires' => true], 2, 3]);
```

Try changing `,` with `=>`

So in your case:

```
$product->components()->sync([$request->component_id => ['quantity'=> $request->quantity]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how i solve my own problem
in Laravel documentation

```
$user->roles()->sync([1 => ['expires' => true], 2, 3]);
```

so to match this

```
$manyToMany = array();
         for ( $i=0 ; $i< count($request->component_id); $i++ )
         {
            $manyToMany[ $request->component_id[$i] ] = ['quantity' =>$request->quantity[$i] ];
         }
         $product->components()->sync($manyToMany);
```

is their is a better solution